# react-router-dom is not installed in command prompt

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am trying to install react-router-dom in my command prompt.But I am facing the problem which is given below.What should I do now?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDxak.png)

Comment: Please, do not use images in questions, they are not searchable and are unnecessary. Just post the error messages as text in your question. Also, you dont seem to be in a << node >> project directory. You are on your desktop...

Answer (score 0):

First thing redirect to your project root directory, then run below command.

```
npm install --save react-router-dom
```